# chocolatey any package install error: String cannot be of zero length

Tags: chocolatey

Having trouble with installing packages with chocolatey:

E.g. (no matter what package, same error)

```
    dtc-msys2 not installed. An error occurred during installation:
     String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: variable
```

More detailed log:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco install dtc-msys2 -v --debug
    Chocolatey v0.10.15
    Chocolatey is running on Windows v 10.0.18362.0
    Attempting to delete file "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe.old".
    Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe.old".
    Command line: "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" install dtc-msys2 -v --debug
    Received arguments: install dtc-msys2 -v --debug
    RemovePendingPackagesTask is now ready and waiting for PreRunMessage.
    Sending message 'PreRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
    [Pending] Removing all pending packages that should not be considered installed...
    [Pending] Removing incomplete install for 'dtc-msys2'
    Performing validation checks.
    Global Configuration Validation Checks:
     - Package Exit Code / Exit On Reboot = Checked
    System State Validation Checks:
     Reboot Requirement Checks:
     - Pending Computer Rename = Checked
     - Pending Component Based Servicing = Checked
     - Pending Windows Auto Update = Checked
     - Pending File Rename Operations = Ignored
     - Pending Windows Package Installer = Checked
     - Pending Windows Package Installer SysWow64 = Checked
    The source 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/' evaluated to a 'normal' source type

    NOTE: Hiding sensitive configuration data! Please double and triple
     check to be sure no sensitive data is shown, especially if copying
     output to a gist for review.
    Configuration: CommandName='install'|
    CacheLocation='C:\Users\RainA\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey'|
    ContainsLegacyPackageInstalls='True'|
    CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds='2700'|WebRequestTimeoutSeconds='30'|
    Sources='https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'|SourceType='normal'|
    Debug='True'|Verbose='True'|Trace='False'|Force='False'|Noop='False'|
    HelpRequested='False'|UnsuccessfulParsing='False'|RegularOutput='True'|
    QuietOutput='False'|PromptForConfirmation='False'|
    AcceptLicense='False'|
    AllowUnofficialBuild='False'|Input='dtc-msys2'|AllVersions='False'|
    SkipPackageInstallProvider='False'|PackageNames='dtc-msys2'|
    Prerelease='False'|ForceX86='False'|OverrideArguments='False'|
    NotSilent='False'|ApplyPackageParametersToDependencies='False'|
    ApplyInstallArgumentsToDependencies='False'|IgnoreDependencies='False'|
    AllowMultipleVersions='False'|AllowDowngrade='False'|
    ForceDependencies='False'|Information.PlatformType='Windows'|
    Information.PlatformVersion='10.0.18362.0'|
    Information.PlatformName='Windows 10'|
    Information.ChocolateyVersion='0.10.15.0'|
    Information.ChocolateyProductVersion='0.10.15'|
    Information.FullName='choco, Version=0.10.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79d02ea9cad655eb'|

    Information.Is64BitOperatingSystem='True'|
    Information.Is64BitProcess='True'|Information.IsInteractive='True'|
    Information.UserName='RainA'|
    Information.UserDomainName='LAPTOP-P5OL4LGT'|
    Information.IsUserAdministrator='True'|
    Information.IsUserSystemAccount='False'|
    Information.IsUserRemoteDesktop='False'|
    Information.IsUserRemote='True'|
    Information.IsProcessElevated='True'|
    Information.IsLicensedVersion='False'|Information.LicenseType='Foss'|
    Information.CurrentDirectory='C:\WINDOWS\system32'|
    Features.AutoUninstaller='True'|Features.ChecksumFiles='True'|
    Features.AllowEmptyChecksums='False'|
    Features.AllowEmptyChecksumsSecure='True'|
    Features.FailOnAutoUninstaller='False'|
    Features.FailOnStandardError='False'|Features.UsePowerShellHost='True'|
    Features.LogEnvironmentValues='False'|Features.LogWithoutColor='False'|
    Features.VirusCheck='False'|
    Features.FailOnInvalidOrMissingLicense='False'|
    Features.IgnoreInvalidOptionsSwitches='True'|
    Features.UsePackageExitCodes='True'|
    Features.UseEnhancedExitCodes='False'|
    Features.UseFipsCompliantChecksums='False'|
    Features.ShowNonElevatedWarnings='True'|
    Features.ShowDownloadProgress='True'|
    Features.StopOnFirstPackageFailure='False'|
    Features.UseRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades='False'|
    Features.IgnoreUnfoundPackagesOnUpgradeOutdated='False'|
    Features.SkipPackageUpgradesWhenNotInstalled='False'|
    Features.RemovePackageInformationOnUninstall='False'|
    Features.ExitOnRebootDetected='False'|
    Features.LogValidationResultsOnWarnings='True'|
    Features.UsePackageRepositoryOptimizations='True'|
    Features.ScriptsCheckLastExitCode='False'|
    ListCommand.LocalOnly='False'|
    ListCommand.IdOnly='False'|ListCommand.IncludeRegistryPrograms='False'|
    ListCommand.PageSize='25'|ListCommand.Exact='False'|
    ListCommand.ByIdOnly='False'|ListCommand.ByTagOnly='False'|
    ListCommand.IdStartsWith='False'|ListCommand.OrderByPopularity='False'|
    ListCommand.ApprovedOnly='False'|
    ListCommand.DownloadCacheAvailable='False'|
    ListCommand.NotBroken='False'|
    ListCommand.IncludeVersionOverrides='False'|
    UpgradeCommand.FailOnUnfound='False'|
    UpgradeCommand.FailOnNotInstalled='False'|
    UpgradeCommand.NotifyOnlyAvailableUpgrades='False'|
    UpgradeCommand.ExcludePrerelease='False'|
    NewCommand.AutomaticPackage='False'|
    NewCommand.UseOriginalTemplate='False'|SourceCommand.Command='unknown'|
    SourceCommand.Priority='0'|SourceCommand.BypassProxy='False'|
    SourceCommand.AllowSelfService='False'|
    SourceCommand.VisibleToAdminsOnly='False'|
    FeatureCommand.Command='unknown'|ConfigCommand.Command='unknown'|
    ApiKeyCommand.Remove='False'|PinCommand.Command='unknown'|
    OutdatedCommand.IgnorePinned='False'|Proxy.BypassOnLocal='True'|
    _ Chocolatey:ChocolateyInstallCommand - Normal Run Mode _
    Installing the following packages:
    dtc-msys2
    By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
    Using 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.
    - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
    - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
    Package 'dtc-msys2' found on source 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
    [NuGet] Installing 'dtc-msys2 1.4.7'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'chocolateyinstall.ps1' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'dtc-1.4.7-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'dtc-1.4.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'gcc-libs-7.3.0-3-i686.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'gcc-libs-7.3.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'LICENSE.txt' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'msys2-runtime-2.11.1-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'msys2-runtime-2.11.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'VERIFICATION.txt' to folder 'dtc-msys2\tools'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'dtc-msys2.nupkg' to folder 'dtc-msys2'.
    [NuGet] Added file 'dtc-msys2.nuspec' to folder 'dtc-msys2'.
    [NuGet] Successfully installed 'dtc-msys2 1.4.7'.

    dtc-msys2 v1.4.7 [Approved]
    dtc-msys2 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
    dtc-msys2 not installed. An error occurred during installation:
     String cannot be of zero length.
    Parameter name: variable

    Chocolatey installed 0/0 packages.
     See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
    Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
    Chocolatey had an error occur:
    System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dtc-msys2\.chocolateyPending' because it is being used by another process.
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.get_file_encoding(String filePath)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.filesystem.DotNetFileSystem.write_file(String filePath, String fileText)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.set_pending(PackageResult packageResult, ChocolateyConfiguration config)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.handle_package_result(PackageResult packageResult, ChocolateyConfiguration config, CommandNameType commandName)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.NugetService.install_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Action`1 continueAction)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.perform_source_runner_function[T](ChocolateyConfiguration config, Func`2 function)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.install_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.GenericRunner.run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container, Boolean isConsole, Action`1 parseArgs)
       at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.ConsoleApplication.run(String[] args, ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container)
       at chocolatey.console.Program.Main(String[] args)
    Exiting with 1
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. There was a similar issue reported in GitHub (https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1933) and turned out I had the same Microchip WinCUPL software installed. Uninstalling WinCUPL solved the problem.